# Class Accessibility Throughout Project

Tags: ios, appdelegate

When I first began working on a long iOS project, my first, I had need for a small class that was readily accessible throughout the project.  At first I passed it around as a property and it became way too much of a headache.

So, even though I've seen posts here advising against it, I created that class in the AppDelegate and access it as needed through a pointer to the AppDelegate.  Then, I would revisit it later.

So, it is now later, I'm approaching release of the project, and I want to deal with this issue.  It works just fine as it is but if it is lousy practice I want to fix it before release.

1. I don't understand why it is lousy practice.  Sometimes you just need a class that is readily available and these seems like as good a way as any to get it.  But there could be some downside I'm not understanding.
2. Assuming I need this class instance (it is very lightweight but heavily used) to be accessible throughout the project (probably about 50 VCs, total), what would be a good alternative to just referencing it via the App Delegate?

TIA for comments.  I hope it doesn't start a war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard-fast rule for for this and hundreds of opinions to be had. Here's my take on it.

> I don't understand why it is lousy practice. Sometimes you just need a class that is readily available and these seems like as good a way as any to get it. But there could be some downside I'm not understanding.

You're right to feel this way and yes sometimes you need a class readily available with your data. It's lousy because it is not how `AppDelegate` should be used. In an ideal world it shouldn't contain lots of unrelated state-data and should serve a singular purpose: delegating system calls to your app. The trick is where do you put your model so that everyone can have access to it?

> Assuming I need this class instance (it is very lightweight but heavily used) to be accessible throughout the project (probably about 50 VCs, total), what would be a good alternative to just referencing it via the App Delegate?

Put your state in a class using the [singleton pattern](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/). It will ensure that only one copy of it is ever created and all your classes should be able to access it. This is a well accepted pattern in the iOS SDK (`NSUserDefaults`, `UIApplication`, etc..). Just beware of this class growing too large or doing too many things. Try your best to keep it simple and focused and the Object-Oriented Police will leave you alone.

Other resources and opinions worth considering:

- http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html
- [Is it a bad practice to use your AppDelegate as your Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708250/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-your-appdelegate-as-your-singleton)
- [Is it good practice to use AppDelegate for data manipulation and Handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155437/is-it-good-practice-to-use-appdelegate-for-data-manipulation-and-handling)